# equivalent of printf in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printf

I was just making a PDFGenerator for my cross platform Phonegap app.

In the report there are fields like Patient name, Patient number, etc. So I thought it'll be a good idea to store these Patient name, Patient number, etc. in variables and change them for every different person and individual.

I don't know how to print variables in between text. Below is my statement for writing a line of text in between which a variable's text value has to be printed out:

```
loremipsum ='Ambulatory Blood Pressure Report\nPatient name: <heregoesthevalueofpatientname>'
```

Please let me know.

Comment: `console.log`? I don't think you've tried very hard to find a solution yourself...

Comment: I also thought of "console.log" at first. But I don't think it's what the author wants to do. From what I understood in the question, the answer below with "+" operator seems the correct way to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine literal strings with variables, you can concatenate them with the `+` operator.

```
loremipsum = 'Ambulatory Blood Pressure Report\nPatient name:' + patientname;
```

And just to be sure that I address the question in the title,

- there's no built-in facility that provides the same formatting functionality as `printf`
- there's no one "standard out" in JavaScript, so displaying text is different depending on how you want it to show up

(this is assuming the JavaScript is for a browser)